# Overlapping intervals to continuous intervals

Tags: sql, date, hive, impala

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (`group` string, id string, valid_from STRING, valid_to STRING);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    ('1', 'NULL', '2022-03-30', '2022-04-29'),
    ('1', '51235', '2022-04-30', '2022-11-01'),
    ('1', '51235', '2022-11-02', '2022-12-07'),
    ('2', 'NULL', '2018-01-01', '2022-01-01'),
    ('2', '1234', '2022-01-02', '2022-07-31'),
    ('2', '1234', '2022-08-01', '2022-08-08'),
    ('2', '5678', '2022-08-09', '2022-09-30'),
    ('2', '5678', '2022-10-01', '2022-12-31')
    ;
```

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (code string, value string, period_from STRING, period_to STRING);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
    ('51235', 'OK', '2022-06-30', '2022-09-29'),
    ('51235', 'NOT OK', '2022-09-30', '2022-12-30'),
    ('1234', 'TBD', '2022-03-31', '2022-06-29'),
    ('1234', 'TBD', '2022-06-30', '2022-09-29')
    ;
```

I want to add the `value` column from `table2` to `table1` but I realized that I cannot use a left join as the validity ranges are overlapping.

Therefore I am searching for a way to change the overlapping intervals to continuous interval in order to output the following result

```
+-------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
| group |  id   | valid_from |  valid_to  | value  |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
|     1 | NULL  | 2022-03-30 | 2022-04-29 | NULL   |
|     1 | 51235 | 2022-04-30 | 2022-06-29 | NULL   |
|     1 | 51235 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-09-29 | OK     |
|     1 | 51235 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-11-01 | NOT OK |
|     1 | 51235 | 2022-11-02 | 2022-12-07 | NOT OK |
|     2 | NULL  | 2018-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | NULL   |
|     2 | 1234  | 2022-01-02 | 2022-03-30 | NULL   |
|     2 | 1234  | 2022-03-31 | 2022-06-29 | TBD    |
|     2 | 1234  | 2022-06-30 | 2022-07-31 | TBD    |
|     2 | 1234  | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-08 | TBD    |
|     2 | 5678  | 2022-08-09 | 2022-09-30 | NULL   |
|     2 | 5678  | 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-31 | NULL   |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
```

I was able to produce the correct intervals with by using an union on both datasets and then decomposing.

```
WITH dates AS
(
         SELECT   id,
                  CASE
                           WHEN Lag(d2) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt ) = dt THEN Date_add(dt, 1)
                           ELSE dt
                  END AS d1,
                  d2
         FROM     (
                           SELECT   id,
                                    type,
                                    dt,
                                    CASE
                                             WHEN Lead(type) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt ) = 1 THEN Date_sub( Lead(dt) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt ), 1 )
                                             ELSE Lead(dt) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt )
                                    END AS d2
                           FROM     (
                                           SELECT 1          AS type,
                                                  id         AS id,
                                                  valid_from AS dt
                                           FROM   table1
                                           UNION ALL
                                           SELECT -1       AS type,
                                                  id       AS id,
                                                  valid_to AS dt
                                           FROM   table1
                                           UNION ALL
                                           SELECT 1           AS type,
                                                  code        AS id,
                                                  period_from AS dt
                                           FROM   table2
                                           UNION ALL
                                           SELECT -1        AS type,
                                                  code      AS id,
                                                  period_to AS dt
                                           FROM   table2 ) `UNION` ) d2
         WHERE    (
                           type = 1
                  OR       d2 = '9999-12-31' ) )
SELECT *
FROM   dates ;
```

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  id   |         d1          |         d2          |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1234  | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 2022-03-30 00:00:00 |
| 1234  | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 | 2022-06-29 00:00:00 |
| 1234  | 2022-06-30 00:00:00 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 1234  | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | 2022-08-08 00:00:00 |
| 51235 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00 | 2022-06-29 00:00:00 |
| 51235 | 2022-06-30 00:00:00 | 2022-09-29 00:00:00 |
| 51235 | 2022-09-30 00:00:00 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00 |
| 51235 | 2022-11-02 00:00:00 | 2022-12-07 00:00:00 |
| 5678  | 2022-08-09 00:00:00 | 2022-09-30 00:00:00 |
| 5678  | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00 |
| NULL  | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| NULL  | 2022-03-30 00:00:00 | 2022-04-29 00:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

However I have no idea how to apply it to table1 given that the `id` is within a `group` that is only given in `table1` not in `table2`

I am running it on hive/impala but an sql solution is also appreciated.